# GCM and GenericPush (Phonegap plugin) not working

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I've been able to generate a registration ID on the device, but in order to send a push notification I had to get an API key, so I got one from the Google Api Console, but its not working. I've tried to send GCM with PushSharp and with some Ruby script. I'm using the correct project ID when calling the method.

pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, { "senderID": "my_project_id", "ecb": "onNotificationGCM" });

Am I missing something, any configuration? For example, iOS APNS with this plugin require a distribution certificate instead of a development certificate. Might be a similar problem.

Comment: Do you get any error response in the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to press a button called "Synchronize Accounts" from my Android device and suddenly I recieved a lot of push notifications.